# sort display on FormGroup with FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a misunderstood how my **FormGroup** is displayed.

Here is my **FormGroup** (not with the fields I wanted to be displayed in this particular order).

[image: render]

I want it in order I added control in FormGroup. If I display each key on addControl, the order is:

- type
- body
- text
- label
- tracking
- additionalTracking

I am adding value in formControl with Addcontrol:

```
      fg.addControl(key, FormCORA);
```

The console log of Object.keys(schema.properties) is in order I want:

["type", "body", "label", "tracking", "additionalTracking"]

The console log of schema is NOT in order I want:

[image: Schema]

How can I do to have label at first for example ?

The html block:

```
                <ng-container *ngIf="tab.content.controls.blockList" [formGroup]="tab.content">
              <div class="mt-3" [id]="tab.label + '-blocklist'">
                <!--
                  Blocks settings
                  Here we construct the form for the blocks configuration
                  We use recursivity to loop over the fileds inside the root formGroup
                  in order to dynamically build forms according to the api exposed schema
                -->
                <nb-card status="danger" *ngIf="tab.content.controls.blockList.status === 'INVALID' && formSubmitted">
                  <nb-card-header class=h-auto>
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please fill up every block <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                  </nb-card-header>
                </nb-card>
                <vccms-blocklist-edito
                  [blockOfType]="editoBlocksAvailable"
                  (blockSchema)="selectedSchema($event)"
                  [langCode]="tab.label"
                ></vccms-blocklist-edito>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
```

My selectedSchema function:

[image: selectedSchema function]

Thanks you in advance for you help ! I am taking any tips.

Comment: You are a bit unclear. What do you need help with?? Please specify

Comment: Hi, I want on the render screenshot the "label" field in first in the form. It looks like in properties in is already in first, but not in my browser.

Comment: can you share a stackblitz?